# Bitbucket pipelines ssh-run: SERVER variable missing

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

When I run the Bitbucket pipeline I always have this strange error I can't resolve:
In the build log

```
   --env=COMMAND="./ansible/deploy-dev.sh" \
   --env=MODE="script" \
   --env=SERVER="$SSH_JUMP_HOST" \
   --env=SSH_KEY="$SSH_JUMP" \
   --env=SSH_USER="$SSH_JUMP_USER" \
...
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for bitbucketpipelines/ssh-run:0.4.0
INFO: Executing the pipe...
/pipe.sh: line 26: SERVER: SERVER variable missing.
```

SERVER variable is set and provided by a repository variable.

bitbucket-pipelines.yml

```yaml
...
    branches:  
      develop:
        - step:
            script:
                - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0
                  variables:
                    SSH_USER: $SSH_JUMP_USER
                    SERVER: $SSH_JUMP_HOST
                    SSH_KEY: $SSH_JUMP
                    MODE: "script"
                    COMMAND: "./ansible/deploy-dev.sh"
```

Someone has a clue, I going nuts !?

Comment: Aaash just a misspelled variable, code is Ok

Comment: If so, please edit the question with a starting disclaimer that you simply misspelled a variable.

Comment: I misspelled a variable, but the real problem was the indentation, which is a bit singular... And which is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atlassian team answered me:

> I've seen this error occur because of incorrect indentation in the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file.
>
> Indentation should be two spaces, except for the level after - step:
> which should be four spaces, as follows. Note also indentation in variables section:
>
> ```yaml
> pipelines:
>   branches:
>     develop:
>       - step:
>           script:
>             - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0
>               variables:
>                 SSH_USER: $SSH_JUMP_USER
>                 SERVER: $SSH_JUMP_HOST
>                 SSH_KEY: $SSH_JUMP
>                 MODE: "script"
>                 COMMAND: "./ansible/deploy-dev.sh"
> ```
>
> Can you check the content of your `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file in our validator here https://bitbucket-pipelines.atlassian.io/validator ?

Comment: I've used lots of pipes with variables and as far as I can tell: question indentation is fine and this answer indentation is wrong

Comment: I just had similar problem, unfortunately I was unable to detect exact reason, but it was something related to formatting, all I've changed is swapped two lines with variables. Mystics in action :). Didn't had similar issues previously, had written quite a lot of pipelines.